inverted function of the script
I want to invert the function of the script, so that 'q' and 'w' are safe in the mouse 5
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then  -- mouse button 5
PressAndReleaseKey("q", "w")
end
end
